Pageview: Disabling and enabling pageview scroll
I have a condition which I want to disable my pageview scroll while my splash screen is loading. I dont want to use native splash screen etc because I need my splash screen persist until my data is fetched and displayed in the screen. I was already able to do this with my singlechildscrollview like this
 SingleChildScrollView(
  physics:
  G.doesSplashAlreadyLoaded?AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics():NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), 
);

but when I'm trying it to do with my pageview I have a weird bug which my pageview doesn't work until I manually changing the page. I tried multiple solutions like these ones
PageView(
            controller: _pageController,
            physics: G.doesSplashAlreadyLoaded?null:NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            onPageChanged: (index) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedIndex = index;
              });
            },
            children: [
              // Home screen content
              AccountFragment(pageColor: G.appBarColors[0]),
              SearchFragment(
                  pageColor: G.appBarColors[0],
                  currentGenre: widget.fromTag),
              HomeFragment(
                pageColor: G.appBarColors[2],
                onTagged: (int index) {
                  _pageController.jumpToPage(1);
                },
              ),
              // Account screen content
            ],
          )

or
PageView(
            controller: _pageController,
            physics: G.doesSplashAlreadyLoaded?ClampingScrollPhysics():NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            onPageChanged: (index) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedIndex = index;
              });
            },
            children: [
              // Home screen content
              AccountFragment(pageColor: G.appBarColors[0]),
              SearchFragment(
                  pageColor: G.appBarColors[0],
                  currentGenre: widget.fromTag),
              HomeFragment(
                pageColor: G.appBarColors[2],
                onTagged: (int index) {
                  _pageController.jumpToPage(1);
                },
              ),
              // Account screen content
            ],
          )

and every possible scroll physics.
Any solutions to this problem will be appreciated
